# To know reason of not added record in NetSuite

Tags: c#, netsuite

Trying to add new customer to NetSuite like it described in sample in manual.

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            ApplicationInfo _appInfo;
            var service = new NetSuiteService();
            service.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();

            _appInfo = new ApplicationInfo();
            _appInfo.applicationId = "FB31C4F2-CA6C-4E5F-6B43-57632594F96";
            service.applicationInfo = _appInfo;


            var passport = new Passport();
            passport.account = "5920356_SB9";
            passport.email = "a@a.com";
            var role = new RecordRef();
            role.internalId = "3";
            passport.role = role;
            passport.password = "@sdkkr_5543";


            try
            {
                var status = service.login(passport).status;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.Out.WriteLine(e.Message);
                throw;
            }


                var cust = new Customer();
                cust.entityId = "XYZ Inc";
                cust.altEmail = "aaa@aaa.aaa";
                var response = service.add(cust);
                Console.Out.WriteLine("response.status.isSuccess " + response.status.isSuccess) ;
                Console.Out.WriteLine("response.status.isSuccessSpecified " + response.status.isSuccessSpecified);


            service.logout();

        }
```

As result I got:

```
response.status.isSuccess False
response.status.isSuccessSpecified True
```

I suppose customer was not inserted. What is wrong and how to know that?

Answer (score 0):

When you call `add()` on the service, the response contains a `status` property which contains a `statusDetail` property.  `statusDetail` is an array of the messages (warnings and errors) that resulted from your `add()`.  You can loop through these to find out why saving your customer record was unsuccessful:

```
var response = service.add(cust);
if (!response.status.isSuccess)
{
    foreach (var error in response.status.statusDetail)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Error creating customer: {error.type} {error.message}");
    }
}
```